# Why Read and ReadAync are producing totally different results

Tags: c#, .net-core, memory-mapping, libvlcsharp

I have been using [this code](https://code.videolan.org/mfkl/libvlcsharp-samples/-/blob/master/PreviewThumbnailExtractor/Program.cs) to capture the webcam and I have been trying to learn from it and make it better. Rider IDE suggested I should use an async variant of `MemoryMappedViewStream.Read` but it doesn't work at all. It produces all-black images suggesting the async and sync methods are totally different. I am wondering why that's the case?

```
// Working:
sourceStream.Read(MemoryMarshal.AsBytes(image.GetPixelMemoryGroup().Single().Span));

// NOT Working:
var bytes = MemoryMarshal.AsBytes(image.GetPixelMemoryGroup().Single().Span).ToArray();
await sourceStream.ReadAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length, token);
```

[Repository](https://github.com/amir734jj/webcam-stream/tree/3bb3ebb2aaf649fc579544f542cd2fd25b7be368) and [line of code](https://github.com/amir734jj/webcam-stream/blob/3bb3ebb2aaf649fc579544f542cd2fd25b7be368/Core/ImageCapture.cs#L120)

Comment: The code is different - in second (async) case you make a copy into the _new_ array, with `ToArray`. Then you read bytes from stream into this copy, but that doesn't affect image, so it remains black.

Comment: @Evk yes. ToArray creates a copy but it should correctly copy the byte array. Can you please elaborate further

Comment: In your first example, you read bytes from `sourceStream` directly into memory location of `image.GetPixelMemoryGroup`, so directly into image. In your second example, you create a _copy_ of (probably black) image memory and then read bytes into that _copy_. So image bytes are now in `bytes` variable, not in image. Image is unaffected and remains black.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you. Is there a way to use the async method correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two versions are not the same. In "sync" version you obtain a reference to memory location of an image via `image.GetPixelMemoryGroup()`. Then you read data from `sourceStream` directly into that location.

In "async" version you again obtain reference to memory location via `image.GetPixelMemoryGroup` but then you do something different - you call `ToArray`. This extension method *copies* bytes from image memory location into new array, the one you hold in `bytes` variable. You then read data from `sourceStream` into that `bytes` array, NOT directly into image memory locaiton. Then you discard `bytes` array, so you read them to nowhere basically.

Now,`MemoryMappedViewStream` inherits from `UnmanagedMemoryStream` and all read\write operations are implemented in `UnmanagedMemoryStream`. This kind of stream represents data in memory and there is nothing async it can do. The only reason it even has `ReadAsync` is because base stream class (`Stream`) has those methods. Even if you manage to make `ReadAsync` work - in this case it will not be asynchornous anyway. As far as I know - `MemoryMappedViewStream` does now allow real asynchronous access, even though it could make sense, since it has underlying file.

In short - I'd just continue with sync version, because there is no benefit in this case to use "async" one. Static analyzer of course doesn't know that, it only sees that there is Async-named analog of the method you use.

Answer (score -2):

```
await sourceStream.ReadAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length, token).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Check like this